# Get my UID using FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to get my `UID` using a simple FQL query, for some reason it returns an empty page.

This is my query:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

Answer (score 0):

`me()` returns the *current* connected user. So you need to append an `access_token`:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid=me()&access_token=XXXXXX
```

P.S.: Facebook has just [released](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/) a Graph API endpoint to query FQL `fql`, so you should be able to do something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid=me()&access_token=XXXXXX
```

*(unfortunately, for some reason it's not working on the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%2buid%2bFROM%2buser%2bWHERE%2buid=me%28%29))*

Comment: Thank you. But, from what I've read, I don't need an access token for getting info from the "user" table, unless it is some more complex data (like friends users). Also, the reason that I am trying to get the current user's uid is for generating access token.

Comment: Using `me()` means you have a connected user, so you need an `access_token` to prove that!

Comment: Ok, then how can I get my UID without access token, even if I don't use FQL?

Comment: programatically, if you don't authorize your app then you can't! you can manually visit the [explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and get your uid.